# Unable to access Users Watch API (Status 403 returned) although Users List API works normally

Tags: kotlin, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I used Service Account key with scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly) to access Google Directory API Users.

With the same setup as below, I can access Users List API ([link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list)).

But when trying to make request to Users Watch API ([link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/watch)), Status 403 returned.

These 2 APIs required the same scope user.readonly that my SA key has.

My domain has already been verified and added into Domain verification screen on GCP Console.

```html
val httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
val jsonFactory = JacksonFactory()
val inputStream = HealthController::class.java.getResourceAsStream("/credentials.json")
        ?: throw FileNotFoundException("/credentials.json")
val credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(inputStream, httpTransport, jsonFactory)
        .toBuilder()
        .setServiceAccountScopes(listOf(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER_READONLY))
        .setServiceAccountUser("admin@example.com")
        .build()
service = Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("Some Name")
        .build()

val channel = Channel()
channel.address = "https://example.com/webhook/v1/google/users"
channel.expiration = Instant.now().toEpochMilli() + 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000
channel.id = "webhook001"
channel.token = "abcxyz"
channel.type = "web_hook"
channel.payload = false

val result = service.users().watch(channel)
        .setDomain("example.com")
        .setViewType("domain_public")
        .execute()
```

I logged the issue to Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171300784

Comment: Have you tried with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user` scope in your token?

Comment: @JoseVasquez No I haven't, should I try it?

Comment: Which JVM version is your Kotlin compiling for execution? This might be affecting your code since Google doesn't directly support Kotlin for **Directory API**, take a look to your version and confirm this is one of the following [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client#ci-status).

Comment: I used kotlin-maven-plugin with jvmTarget to be 1.8

Comment: but JVM version on my local machine is 11

Comment: After further investigation, reproducing your code, using your same JVM target version and JVM on my environment I can use the **watch** method. This 403 error might be produced because the the version of your google packages which can be **Deprecated**. Can you please adapt your code an try with [ServiceAccountCredentials](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-auth-library/latest/com/google/auth/oauth2/ServiceAccountCredentials.html) instead of [GoogleCredentials](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-auth-library/latest/com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials.html) and make sure that you adapt...

Comment: your credentials `HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(googleCredentials);` by using the [HttpRequestInitializer](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer.html) Interface and [HttpCredentialsAdapter](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-auth-library/latest/index.html?com/google/auth/http/HttpCredentialsAdapter.html) Class. Otherwise please confirm which versions you are using in your google dependencies.

Comment: @JoseVasquez: thanks for a great insight, I'll give it a try.

I don't even know about class ServiceAccountCredentials, I know about class GoogleCredentials from Google Admin SDK documentation site example.

And yes, with latest version of Google API oauth package, this class is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

### Google Directory API doesn't support Kotlin directly it depends on the target compilation

#### Prerequisites

Make sure that you have [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) activated.

#### Workaround

As an approach in JAVA (you can transpile this code to Kotlin if needed) first of all use the [watch method](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/admin/directory/Directory.Users.Watch.html) of the official documentation as well as the [Channel class](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/admin/directory/model/Channel.html), I'll put the package dependency in a comment:

```
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

// com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials
GoogleCredentials credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH))
            .createScoped(SCOPES)
            .createDelegated("impersonated@example.com");

// com.google.api.client.http
HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);

// com.google.api.services.admin.directory.Directory.Builder
Directory service = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, requestInitializer)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

// com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.Channel
Channel channel = new Channel();
channel.setAddress("https://example.com/webhook/v1/google/users");
channel.setExpiration(Instant.now().toEpochMilli() + 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
channel.setId("webhook001");
channel.setToken("abcxyz");
channel.setType("web_hook");
channel.setPayload(false);

System.out.println(service.users().watch(channel)
                .setDomain("example.com")
                .setViewType("domain_public")
                .execute());
```

### Reference

[Javadoc Directory API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/admin/directory/package-tree.html)